# Retrieve all display names from fillable pdf form

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

Refer http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf
It has fields like **Given Name, Family Name** with text box to take inputs

Similarly, it has **Gender and Favourite colour** field with combo box for input selection.

I would like to retrieve all field names that are available in form.

I used `pdField.getFullyQualifiedName()` to retrieve the name as Given name, but it returns **Given Name Text Box** instead of **Given Name**

I have used **Apache PDFBox** library

code snippet:

```
 java.io.File file = new java.io.File("/Users/harshad/Desktop/SampleTemplate.pdf");
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
            PDAcroForm pDAcroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

            List<PDField> pdFieldList = pDAcroForm.getFields();
            for (PDField pdField : pdFieldList) {

              System.out.println("Qualified name : " + pdField.getFullyQualifiedName());
              System.out.println("Partial name : " + pdField.getPartialName());
              System.out.println("Alternate name : " + pdField.getAlternateFieldName());
              System.out.println("Mapping name : " + pdField.getMappingName());
              System.out.println("###########################");
            }
```

[image]

**I want to retrieve the labels
Given Name, Family Name, Address 1, Address 2, Deutsch, English, etc**

Comment: The form field has the name "Given Name Text Box". It does not have the name "Given Name"; merely the text "Given Name" is displayed in the vicinity of the form field. Actually the field does have an alternate name, but that alternate name is "First name", not "Given Name".

Comment: @mkl every field does not have alternate name Example: Qualified name : Address 2 Text Box Partial name : Address 2 Text Box Alternate name : null Mapping name : null

Comment: (Unrelated) use `getFieldTree` instead of `getFields`, see javadoc.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr That isn't helpful to retrieve the labels of textbox, combo box, checkbox. I have added image in question for more understanding.

Comment: What you call "labels" of those fields actually is not directly associated with the fields inside the pdf. Those labels merely are static text which is drawn in the vicinity of the field in question, sometimes before it, sometimes after it, and in other forms also sometimes above, sometimes beneath, and sometimes inside. You can try and write code using text extraction with coordinates to compare text and field coordinates and deduce which text might be a label for which field. That is not implemented as a utility method in pdfbox.