# How to get a input field's title using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I want to get all fields from pdf file and get all required data: field type, id, default value, title, popup text and so on.
I can get almost all data except title. If I got it right, correct field titles I can find in the pdf content chapter, but how I can match them to fields?
I use this code to get fields information.

```
try(PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(pdfFileBinary)) {
    PDAcroForm acroForm = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    if (acroForm == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    return acroForm.getFields()
            .stream()
            .flatMap(unfoldFunction)
            .map(PdfFieldImpl::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Can't parse pdf document");
}
```

If someone know the solution but with different library, it would be also great.
Sorry if it is too stupid question for you :)

Comment: What do you mean by *title*? Probably the same as the poster of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67684995/1729265) meant by "label"? In that case read the comments there: Determining those labels or titles in general is a non-trivial exercise due to the wealth of variants in form design.

Comment: yeah. You are right. As title I mean label. Thx for guiding me.